# Code completion for CodeIgniter with zend studio not working

Tags: codeigniter, ide, zend-studio

Ok so i tried doing what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080068/how-to-get-zend-studio-autocomplete-with-codeigniter) post says about adding code completion to zend studio, even with the libraries added code hinting/completion still fails to show. As my libraries are growing it's becoming more important to have this feature as i'm starting to forget what my methods were actually designed for or what there called. from within a controller, model maybe even view i would like to have it show after typing `$this->router->(show completion)` as an example. I have also added application/libraries path for my custom made libraries and they too wont show.

I have done a bit off google searching but most just say to do what the above post says. I attempted to try `/* @var $var Class */` but wasnt able to assign it with a property eg. `/* @var $this->router CI_Router */` only a standard variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved simply by doing comment as such

> /**
>   
> * @var CI_Loader
>   
> */
>   
> $load

and not just doing

> /* @var ........ */

Comment: It's the missing double star that make problems IMO!

Comment: Unfortunately views will not work as they're being created dynamically and doesn't specifically extend the controller class.